# For which $m$ does the equation $\lvert x^2+5x+4 \rvert +x-m=0$ have more than two real solutions?

Tags: quadratics

When dealing with problems containing quadratic equations, I've never come across one that deals with a number of roots that is bigger than 2.

I've tried breaking up the function into two parts.

$x^2+6x+4-m=0$ for $x^2+5x+4\ge0$
and
$-x^2-4x-4-m=0$   for $x^2+5x+4<0$

Now imagining the graph of the function $\lvert x^2+5x+4\rvert$, I came to the idea that the equation in the problem should have more than 2 roots if at least one of the roots of the absolute part is smaller than 0 (under the x axis, thus 2+ roots).

The problem is, doing those two inequalities ($f(x_1)<0$ and $f(x_2)<0$), I get that m is greater than $-1$ or $-4$. I'm sure I'm on the right track because a few of the possible intervals contain these two numbers but I'm not sure where I made a mistake.

Edit:

The possible solutions are
A: $[1,4]$
B: $[-1,0]$
C: $[0,4]$
D: $[-4,-1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that drawing [the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D%7Cx%5E2%2B5x%2B4%7C%2Bx) of $y=x+|x^2+5x+4|$ will help.

This is because the number of real roots of $|x^2+5x+4|+x-m=0$ equals the number of the intersection points between $y=m$ and $y=x+|x^2+5x+4|$.

Since $y=m$ is a horizontal line, the graph should tell you the answer. As a result, the answer will be B. I hope this helps.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the second sentence, I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: Understood, thank you :) Say you got this problem and weren't able to graph the function, is there any way to get this result without looking at it? I'm asking because in the setting I will be solving problems like this I most likely won't have access to a graph of a function like this (and I wouldn't know to graph it by hand).

Comment: @JohnDoe: An easy example : $x^2=4$ can be interpreted as the $x$ coordinate of the intersection points between the graph of $y=x^2$ and the graph of $y=4$. Sorry:) I deleted my comment to improve it.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Well, I think you can get the graphs. Just draw $y=x^2+6x+4$ for $x\le -4$ or $x\ge -1$ and $y=-x^2-4x-4$ for $-4\le x\le -1$. Don't you know how to draw parabolas?

Comment: Welp! I do, for some reason that -x outside the absolute value was scaring me, never had to graph something like that, but you are right, it's not far more complex than a simple parabola.  
Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe: You are welcome! Yes, you can do it. Very glad if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \vert x^2+5x+4 \vert + x$. We then have
\begin{align}
f(x) & 
=
\begin{cases}
x^2+6x+4 & x \notin (-4,-1)\\
-(x+2)^2 & x \in (-4,-1)
\end{cases}
\end{align}

[image]

Hence, $g(x) = f(x) - m$ shifts the graph down by $m$. We see that $f(x)$ has $3$ roots.

1. Shifting down any bit will reduce the number of roots to $2$. Hence, $m > 0$ results in two roots for $g(x)$.
2. Also, note that shifting up by bringing the sharp peak at $x=-1$ above the $X$ axis but the sharp peak at $x=-4$ remaining below the $X$ axis also produces $2$ roots. The value of $f(x)$ at $x=-1$ is -1, while the value at $x=-4$ is $-4$. Hence, for any $m \in (-4,-1)$ we again have two roots.

Hence, to summarize:

1. $m>0$ produces $2$ roots.
2. $m=0$ produces $3$ roots.
3. $m \in (-1,0)$ produces $4$ roots.
4. $m=-1$ produces $3$ roots.
5. $m \in (-4,-1)$ produces $2$ roots.
6. $m=-4$ produces $1$ root.
7. $m<-4$ produces no root.

Comment: Thank you. The question however, is  asking when the function will have ***more*** than two roots so the answer would be $[-1,0]$.

Had I not been able to get the graph of this function, how would I go around to getting this result?